# Angular Can't access data outside of subscibe method

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-services

I am using firestore cloud with angularfire2, I trying to get access to data for single document to display into my template, the data is only availabe within the subscription method.

This is the method from my service where I fetch the document

```js
getDataDetails(id: any) {
    this.dataDocumment = this.afs.doc('data/' + id);
    return this.dataDocumment.valueChanges();
}
```

and this my ngOnInit component method

```js
ngOnInit() {
      this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      this.dataD = this.dataService.getDataDetails(this.id)
        .subscribe(
      res => {
          this.dataD = res;
          console.log(this.dataD);
      });
      console.log(this.dataD);
      }
```

The first `console.log(this.dataD)` within the subscribe scope successfully display the document data

```
{adresse: "Rue de France #10", bureau: "78", centre: "Lycée Français", cin: "751-02-785-782-002", commune: "Paris", …}
```

but the second one display

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}
```

Any idea of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying access the variable outside the synchronous context
>   while subscribing to an observable you are doing an asynchronous
>   operation and the console.log is in a synchronous can text so by the
>   time you access the variable in the console.log it is not yet
>   populated due to the subscribe being in a asynchronous context

What you can do is try and do all the operations related to that variable in the subscribe call itself

Comment: How would you suggest me to do the operations in the subscribe?what I want is the to be able to bind the document fields to my component template

Comment: it's a common error equal a variable to an Observable and expect that we should receive in the variable the values of the observable. NOT. it's an error write this.data=miservice.method().subscribe(..). -The only thing that we get is that this.data become the same observable- you must equal the value in the subscribe: miservice.method().subscribe(res=>this.data=res). Only when the observable ends, we get the value in this.data. (so you can not use this.data until then). This can looks like a big headache, but is the basic of Observables -and Angular hence- and... .

Comment: ..it's great, We don't need worry about when the observable ends: when the observable ends, we'll see the data on screen "magically"